# How to send messages of offline user after getting online in java websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I am trying to write a chat using webcocket, for offline users I have used java Queue, If user is offline I keep messages in a Queue and when user gets online I check if Queue is empty and if it's not, using a loop i remove each messages from Queue. The problem is it just sends last message to user even though all messages are in queue,
here is my onOpen method:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{room}/{user}", encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class, decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class)
 public class ChatEndpoint {


private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
private static final Map<String, Queue<ChatMessage>> userMessageBuffer = new HashMap<>();

@OnOpen
public void open(final Session session,
        @PathParam("room") final String room,
        @PathParam("user") final String userId) {

    log.info("session openend and bound to room: " + room);
    // session.getUserProperties().put("room", room);
    session.getUserProperties().put("user", userId);

    Queue<ChatMessage> userMsgs = userMessageBuffer.get(userId);
    ChatMessage sendChat = new ChatMessage();

    if (userMsgs != null && !userMsgs.isEmpty()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < userMsgs.size(); i++) {

            sendChat = userMsgs.remove();
            System.out.println("size!!!!!! " + sendChat.getMessage());
            try {

                    session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(sendChat);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (EncodeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}}
```

Does any one knows where is the problem?

Comment: You do realize that `userMsgs.size()` will return smaller and smaller values each time the for loop loops?

Comment: what is your message broker?

Comment: yes it gets smaller every time

Comment: what is a message broker?

Comment: Unless you specifically need `i` for something, just use a `while (userMsgs.size() > 0)` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Change your for loop to, for (ChatMessage sendChat : userMsgs) which is a lot cleaner and does not employ a redundant integer counter. Neither do you need to worry about the size of the queue.

Comment: I did all of these and still not working , in case of using while it doesn't send anything

Comment: @nazila Can you post your updated code separately in the question? Don't change the current code but post it under Edit or Update

Comment: I think the problem is in open method is not a right place to send message but i don't know where to do that

Comment: @karthik I replaced your code with my for loop,

Comment: @nazila but you said that you were able to send the last message? How was it sending that?  I dont think the problem is with the placement of onopen.

Comment: @nazila the problem is not with your `onOpen` or `send`. You can do that there is nothing wrong in that. Check here :  https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.4/index/websocket-api.html#d0e645

Comment: problem solved, I don't know why but while loop did not work and  for (ChatMessage sendChat : userMsgs) worked, @Tuxxy_Thang Thank you

Comment: Glad it solved it. The reason will be that it does not do what Karthik described, which is what your code was doing and I suspect that his suposition that you only had 2 messages in the queue which is why you sent the last message is correct too. In essence my for loop starts at the head and sequentially continues towards tail, without skipping anything, until the queue is exhausted.

Comment: @Tuxxy_Thang what do you mean by  **the reason will be that it does not do what Karthik described, which is what your code was doing**?

Comment: @karthik lol, that was a cack handed way of agreeing with what you said about the OP original code, in why it was probably only sending the last message. I hate these small comment boxes :D

Answer (score 4):

I did not check the complete code, but certainly

```
      for (int i = 0; i < userMsgs.size(); i++)
```

is your problem. Because you are using `i++` and checking `userMsgs.size()` as a condition in for loop. So you are increasing `i` by `1` and decreasing `userMsgs` size by 1, effectively you will be able access only half of the elements in the queue.

say you have 8 elements in the queue, initially  (Imagine this like `Admiral General Aladeen` explaining about round shaped missile)

```
               i=0 and userMsgs.size()=8
               i=1 and userMsgs.size()=7
               i=2 and userMsgs.size()=6
               i=3 and userMsgs.size()=5
               i=4 and userMsgs.size()=4 // comes out of loop.
```

you should use a while loop instead,

```
  while(!userMsgs.isEmpty()){
   .....
  }
```

You said you are able to send only last message to the user, may be that is because you have only 2 messages in the queue. I know it's rare but that should be the case according your code.